# "Select Files" Images disappearing in Low Variables

Tags: low-variables

When moving the MySQL between environments (Live, Dev, Local) the files in "Select File" fields disappear The files are still on the server (All environments) because I just select them again and they work.

I'm running...

- EE.2.7.0
- Low Variables 2.3.5
- PHP 5.4.10 (On all environments)

Comment: Do you mean that the selection is "forgotten" or that the files are not appearing in the (left) list of all files?

Comment: @Low The selection is forgotten. The files are on the server and in the file list to select it again. But it just vanishes out of the select field and I have to select it again.

Comment: Are you moving over the contents of exp_global_variables, too?

Comment: @Low The full database just gets exported from one environment, then imported on the other. It's weird because the files are there, it just forgets the selection in LV.

Comment: Can you add the details for your upload folder preferences here, too?